# como hacer que mi app se actualice sola a los usuarios

Tags: android

Tengo una consulta.

ya tengo creada mi app, y la he subido a la play store. el punto es que cada vez que hago una actualización tengo que avisar a mis usuarios que hay una nueva actualización para que ellos la descarguen.

mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que mi app se les actualice sola sin necesidad de que ellos tengan que entrar a la play store y le tengan que dar actualizar.

Agradezco su apoyo.

Saludos.

Comment: Estoy totalmente en contra de que las apps se actualicen solas, es el usuario quién debe decidir, ¿qué ocurre si la nueva versión incluye una opción nueva que el usuario no quiere? Debes dejar que sea el usuario quién decida, otra cosa es notificarle que hay una nueva versión, pero dejar que la app sola se actualice va en contra de la ética básica. Es solo mi opinión, claro, se que harás lo que quieras, pero lo digo por si hay suerte y lo tienes en consideración.

Answer (score 1):

si quieres crear una app que se actualize automaticamente Como la aplicación de Facebook  si ese es tu caso sigue leyendo.

> Si desea verificar si su aplicación tiene actualizaciones (sin
>      interactuar con Google Play), deberá sondear un servidor
>      (proporcionando su versión actual) y dejar que el servidor verifique
>      si hay una versión más nueva disponible. Si ese es el caso, permita
>      que el servidor responda con un registro de cambios y una URL a la
>      versión más reciente

Afortunadamente, hay bibliotecas para hacer esto:

- [android auto update](https://github.com/feicien/android-auto-update). La biblioteca china, pero debería ser el
  truco, lejos de la biblioteca más popular para hacer esto, pero esto
  puede ser solo porque Google Play no está disponible en China
- [AppUpdateChecker](https://github.com/mitmel/AppUpdateChecker) Una forma simple que no es de Market para
  mantener su aplicación actualizada. Todo lo que necesita para
  configurar es una URL que apunta a un documento JSON que describe los
  cambios de su aplicación.
- [android auto updater client](https://github.com/NDMAC/android-auto-updater-client) Este proyecto permite actualizar
  automáticamente una aplicación APK en ejecución usando un servidor de
  actualización privado (ver apk-updater) en lugar del actualizador de
  Google Play. También viene con una secuencia de comandos del
  servidor. SmartUpdates. Biblioteca anterior, pero con instrucciones
  en inglés y también proporciona una secuencia de comandos del
  servidor.
- [AndroidSmartUpdates](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidSmartUpdates). Biblioteca anterior, pero con instrucciones
  en inglés y también proporciona una secuencia de comandos del
  servidor.
- [WVersionManager](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager). Comprueba si hay actualizaciones, pero la
  actualización real debe descargarse de Play Store.

Comment: he visto varias aplicaciones que se actualizan sin siquiera uno la toque, por ejemplo facebook cada vez que hay actualizaciones el solito se actualiza. y todo esto lo hacen desde la play store, hay que configurar algo mas en mi app. disculpa por preguntar pero soy nuevo en android.

Comment: Comentario original sin Google Translate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34251748/1136132

Comment: no use google translate ahah fue mi traduccion quiza muy literal en ingles al spanish lol